# Output parameter in a Singleton

Tags: c#, singleton

Is the following tread safe in a singleton pattern? I used the fourth singleton pattern in http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

I'm concerned using an output parameter will break the whole principal.

```
public sealed class eCacheContent
{
        private static readonly eCacheContent instance = new eCacheContent();
        private ICacheManager _Cache = CacheFactory.GetCacheManager(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ContentCache"].ToString());
        // for access method control locking
        private static object syncRoot = new object();

        // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
        // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
        static eCacheContent() { }

        private eCacheContent() { }

        public static eCacheContent Instance
        {
            get
            {
                return instance;
            }
        }

        public bool TryGetValue(string key, out eContent output)
        {
            lock (syncRoot)
            {

                if (Contains(key))
                {
                    ObjectCloner helper = new ObjectCloner();
                    eContent tmp = (eContent)this._Cache.GetData(key);
                    output = helper.Clone(tmp);
                    return true;
                }


                output = new eContent();
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void Add(string key, object value)
        {
            // Initiase the helper class for cloning
            if (CheckKeyIfValid(key))
            {
                ObjectCloner helper = new ObjectCloner();
                // Remove if already exist
                this.Remove(key);
                // Add carbon copy
                _Cache.Add(key, helper.Clone(value));
            }
        }

        public void Flush()
        {
            _Cache.Flush();
        }

        private bool Contains(string key)
        {
            if (CheckKeyIfValid(key))
                return _Cache.Contains(key);
            else
                return false;
        }

        private void Remove(string key)
        {
            if (Contains(key))
            {
                _Cache.Remove(key);
            }
        }

        private bool CheckKeyIfValid(string key)
        {
            if ((key != null) && (key.Trim().Length != 0))
                return true;

            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Your methods are *instance* methods, not `static` - I assume that's a mistake?

Comment: I would say this is indeed a bad idea. While you lock this code it is possible that some other thread is accessing your "out"-ed variable. Do never try to lock on this var as this might result in a dead lock. So I would say: Bad idea. Anyway why using ref at all? Just return string. This is not c++, members are reference counted.

Comment: I see where I went wrong in my thinking. It's always helpfull to get an outside look...thanks

Comment: @Samuel the OP isn't locking on that variable though, they have a specific `syncRoot` object used for locking. *"This is not C++, members are referenced counted"* - that's not accurate either, C# **does not** use reference counting, the GC traverses the object graph during a collection and disposes of any unreachable objects.

Comment: @James thanks for pointing it out. I am actually aware that GC deletes all non-rooted objects. But IMHO in a broader sense this can be regarded as reference counted where a reference means any path of an object that is rooted (count of 1), and 0 if none :/ But you are right, bad explanation by me.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm concerned using an output parameter will break the whole principal.

In what way do you think an `out` parameter breaks the principle of a Singleton? By [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) a singleton class "*restricts the Instantiation of a class to one object*" - your `Instance` property ensures that.

Your `TryGetValue` method is a helper method for pulling out cached versions of `eContent`, this is completely separate from your `eCacheContent` class.

Comment: yes I realise that there will only be one.  Never saw an output peratermer in any of the example and was not sure if it might be shared accross users in case the bump heads. Since all content objects are cached I'm expecting a lot of traffic on this singleton.